# Best Stack/Solution to create a Single Page app that allows multiple users to contribute and see changes in real time

Tags: asp.net, database, windows, entity-framework

Good Day,

I am trying to build a very small display application for a database. The application will need to display data dynamically from a connected database without the user refreshing constantly but the user needs to have a sync rate < 5 sec. I have looked into a web API and MVC structures (CRUD). Which work great for a single user input but I need the display to change based on any changes made by any user to the database. The application will only have a small amount of users (<20) and due to our connection, the lighter the application is the better. A web application would be ideal so that the client-side is display and input only.

I was hoping to get some feedback as to which technology to start to look at for the front end. I have built the database with Entity Framework.

Any input would be appreciated.

Regards,

Peter

Comment: The question seems to be opinion based: You may want to see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @Progressive while the question invites opinions, the answer is not opinionated, since we have a finite set of possibilities and they all should be looked at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### WebSockets

The very best solution is to use [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API). WebSockets consist an advanced technology, which creates a duplex connection between the client and the server and whenever the server needs to be sending data, it can send it to active connections. Since you are using ASP.NET, [SignalR](https://www.asp.net/signalr) would be very helpful for you. You can watch [very good video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fr4rWZIDdzs)s about SignalR.

#### Push Notifications

You can also use push notifications to listeners to push. The [Push API](https://www.tpeczek.com/2017/12/push-notifications-and-aspnet-core-part.html) would help you in this. This is not as good as WebSockets, since the client will have to work with HTTP requests if it was to send requests to the server.

#### Polling

You can create your own API function at the server and use polling to send requests to it. An example for a general-purpose poller is this one:

```
function Initializable(params) {
    this.initialize = function(key, def, private) {
        if (def !== undefined) {
            (!!private ? params : this)[key] = (params[key] !== undefined) ? params[key] : def;
        }
    };
}
function Poller(params) {
    Initializable.call(this, params);

    var that = this;
    this.initialize("url", window.location.href);
    this.initialize("interval", 5000);
    this.initialize("type", "POST");
    this.initialize("method", "POST");
    this.initialize("data", {});
    this.initialize("strict", true);
    this.initialize("isWebSocket", false);
    this.initialize("message", "Poll");
    this.initialize("webSocketHandler", undefined);
    if (this.isWebSocket && !this.webSocketHandler) {
        this.initialize("module", module);
        this.initialize("page", page);
        this.webSocketHandler = new WebSocketHandler({
            ConnectNow: true,
            module: this.module,
            page: this.page,
            message: this.message,
            Message: function(e) {
                that.done(e.data);
            }
        });
    }

    var defaultFunction = function() {};

    this.initialize("done", defaultFunction);
    this.initialize("fail", defaultFunction);
    this.initialize("always", defaultFunction);

    //WS
    this.initialize("isWebSocketPrepared", function() {
        return true;
    });
    this.initialize("sendingWebSocket", function() {});
    this.initialize("handleUnpreparedWebSocket", function() {});
    this.initialize("sendWSData", function(message) {
        if (that.webSocketHandler.isReady()) {
            if (that.isWebSocketPrepared()) {
                that.webSocketHandler.send(JSON.stringify({
                    module: module,
                    page: page,
                    message: message
                }));
                that.sendingWebSocket();
            } else {
                that.handleUnpreparedWebSocket();
            }
        } else {
            that.handleUnpreparedWebSocket();
        }
    });

    this.isRunning = function() {
        return !!params.intervalID;
    };

    this.run = function() {
        if (this.strict && (this.green === false)) {
            return;
        }
        this.green = false;
        if (!that.isWebSocket) {
            $.ajax({
                url: this.url,
                method: this.method,
                data: this.data
            }).done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                that.green = true;
                that.done(data, textStatus, jqXHR);
            }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                that.green = true;
                that.fail(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
            }).always(function(param1, param2, param3) {
                that.green = true;
                that.always(param1, param2, param3);
            });
        } else {
            that.sendWSData(that.message);
        }
    };

    this.start = function() {
        if (!params.intervalID) {
            this.run();
            params.intervalID = setInterval(this.run.bind(this), this.interval);
        }
    };

    this.stop = function() {
        if (!!params.intervalID) {
            clearInterval(params.intervalID);
            params.intervalID = undefined;
        }
    };

}
```

#### Forever Frame

You can also use forever frames, which are `iframe`s which are loading forever. Read more here: https://vinaytech.wordpress.com/2008/09/25/long-polling-vs-forever-frame/

Comment: Yeah I have been leaning down the signalR pathway. I will keep looking and developing. Thanks for the input!

Comment: @PeterCarmen if my answer answered your question, then you might consider accepting it as the correct answer.